# Extracting a single entry from text files opened with readtable

Tags: matlab, data-analysis

I'm very new to working with Matlab so this may be fairly simple.

My problem involves working with a large number of text files to extract a value corresponding with a specific variable from each. I'm running a loop to open all of my files and would like to create an array with all of the extracted values at the end.

In addition, readtable is bringing in two empty columns that I would like to get rid of but I am unsure how to go about this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Could you put an example with your problem or some code with what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi so at the moment I have a method to get the data I want but it will encounter some problems if the length of the text file were to change. What I have at the moment is::::: opts = detectImportOptions(myFiles, 'NumHeaderLines', 26);

    opts.MissingRule = 'fill';

    opts.ExtraColumnsRule = 'ignore';

    T = readtable(myFiles, opts);

   

   

   

    x = T.Var4(1);

    wl= T.Var2(1);    I'd like to be able to do this a bit less manually. My data is a list of wavelengths and associated values and I need the one closest to 1064nm. Sorry for the formatting, new to this.

Comment: If you want to get the nearest value to some number maybe this [link](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/194618-how-to-find-the-index-of-the-closest-value-to-some-number-in-1d-array) help you.